# How to determine percentage of CPU used by a user from sa command output?

Tags: linux, cpu

I am using `sa -m` to display CPU usage details of each user on an RHEL 7 system. It displays the information in below format.

```
oracle                              15335   88164.18re     176.77cp         0avio    167603k
root                                 9640    8294.42re      10.90cp         0avio     33737k
3rdeye                                250       0.33re       0.04cp         0avio     28358k
sshd                                    4       2.11re       0.00cp         0avio     22068k
dbus                                    2       0.00re       0.00cp         0avio      7600k
smmsp                                   2       0.00re       0.00cp         0avio     21408k
```

I found this site which gives a brief info about the fields. (https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html#comments)

**re** -  “real time” in wall clock minutes
**cp** - sum of system and user time in cpu minutes
**k**  - cpu-time averaged core usage, in 1k units

Is there a way to calculate the percentage of CPU usage for each user from this data?

**UPDATE 1:**

I am adding this update since Alex is suggesting to use a script which is based on top command to obtain CPU usage per user. I have been using a script with that logic (`top -b -n 1 -u $USERNAME | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }'`)to calculate CPU usage of a user. But if I observe closely it looks like the script does not give you the correct value. I somewhat found a reason for that. When you run top it shows a value for CPU usage then keeps updating it every 3 (default) seconds. But the initial value seems to be constant every time you run top.

```
[root@myserver unix]# top -b -n 1 -u oracle |grep -i "cpu"|head -1
%Cpu(s):  5.6 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id, 12.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
[root@myserver unix]# top -b -n 1 -u oracle |grep -i "cpu"|head -1
%Cpu(s):  5.6 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id, 12.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
[root@myserver unix]# top -b -n 1 -u oracle |grep -i "cpu"|head -1
%Cpu(s):  5.6 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id, 12.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
[root@myserver unix]# top -b -n 1 -u oracle |grep -i "cpu"|head -1
%Cpu(s):  5.6 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id, 12.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
```

I executed top for the user oracle four times and it keeps giving the same values for CPU usage. I could see it clearly when I run top without -b and -n options:

```
# top -u oracle
top - 08:47:44 up 3 days,  2:58,  2 users,  load average: 2.21, 1.69, 1.42
Tasks: 1084 total,   3 running, 1081 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5.6 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id, 12.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
```

Notice how it starts with those values for CPU usage. Ofcourse, then after 3 seconds it refreshes and starts displaying correct values. This is the reason I want to change my approach in determining CPU usage per user. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Have you considered using the native process accounting metrics ?  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-varaccountpacct-or-varlogaccountpacct-file/

Comment: Please guide me on what exactly I should be looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you an alternative way. And it's through the package [systat](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/sysstat/) (the link is for arch), and it provides commands as `mpstat`, `iostat` and many others.

***mpstat's output:***

```
Linux 4.9.43-1-lts (laptop)     18/08/2017  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

19:51:50     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
19:51:50     all    2,18    0,03    0,58    0,07    0,00    0,02    0,00    0,00    0,00   97,13
```

***iostat's output:***

```
Linux 4.9.43-1-lts (laptop)     18/08/2017  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2,18    0,03    0,60    0,07    0,00   97,13

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               3,13        28,15        80,47    1029654    2943525
```

Comment: In what way can `mpstat` attribute cpu usage to an individual user ?

Comment: Ah I've misunderstood the question. So if you want for every user you could even write down a script like this.      You take all the user avaiable in the system through: ```cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd``` and after that you pass every single user in the command 
```top -b -n 1 -u username | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }' ```. Of course you need ```top``` and ```username``` should be substituted